# XCode 9....cant open workspace, stuck on Loading

Tags: ios, xcode

I have this project that I haven't used in a while and since last using it, I have upgraded to Xcode 9 and High Sierra, now I can't open my workspace file :(

This is as far as I get:

[image]

And nothing, this project is in an iCloud folder, I have tried taking out of an iCloud folder, removed some folders from my Library folder...still nothing, this is the only recent copy I have for this project and I cant open the xcworkspace file. PLEASE HELP!

**UPDATE**

I removed contents.xcworkspacedata from my workspace Contents folder and removed project.xcworkspace from my xcodeproj file Content folder and now I am able to open the project, but it says no files when there is, I can open the xcodeproj file and the files are there, also I have no Schemes either.

[image]

Comment: Did you ever solve this?  I am having the same problem

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I had similar problem, I fixed by turning off my wifi, then open my project and turning on my wifi again. iCloud sync was the problem.